# Setting up a volume integral over sphere at some arbitrary position

Tags: integration

How do I set up an integral for some function $f(x,y,z)$ in Cartesian coordinates (maybe $f(x,y,z) = x+y+z$) over a three-dimensional domain for a sphere of some radius $R$ centered at some position $(x_q,y_q,z_q)$?  For the cube of side-length $j$ centered at the origin, we can write: $\int_0^j \int_0^j \int_0^j f(x,y,z) dx dy dz$, but its unclear to me how to do this for the more general sphere centered at some arbitrary position.

Answer (score 0):

You use polar coordinates, so $r$ is the radius and $\theta$ and $\phi$, are the angles.

Then let $x-x_q=r\sin\theta\cos\phi$, $y-y_q=r\sin\theta\sin\phi$, and $z-z_q=r\cos\theta$.

Now $r=(x-x_q)^2+(y-y_q)^2+(z-z_q)^2$, and $0\leq r\leq R$, where $R$ is the radius of the sphere.

To create a full sphere we let $0\leq\theta\leq \pi$, and $0\leq\phi\leq 2\pi$.

Then under these coordinates, $dV=dxdydz\to r^2\sin\theta drd\theta d\phi$ Now our general integral is:

$\large \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^R r^2\sin\theta drd\theta d\phi$

Comment: Notice that the standard integral is the same as if we were centred at zero (since the volume of the sphere doesn't change if you move it), but if you want to integrated over the sphere with $f(x,y,z)$, you will need to fiddle with things to find $f(r,\theta,\phi)$, and thats where the position of the sphere changes things.